# React Props not being returned, but being returned in console

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following project to teach myself React and some basic back end stuff- [Digital Sign In](https://github.com/samakers/digi-sign-in)

I am receiving JSON from my API, mapping through this and returning Rows with props to be rendered.

In 'client\src\components\Tables.jsx' I can output the data from the API in the console, but I cannot render this on the web-page.

I know it's probably something really daft but I've went away, came back and still can't figure it out.

Another pair of eyes on this will be much appreciated.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Table from "react-bootstrap/Table";
import Row from "./Row";

class Tables extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      people: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("/api/employees")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(people =>
        this.setState({ people }, () =>
          console.log("Employees fetched...", people)
        )
      );
  }

  render() {

    const rows = this.state.people.map(person => {
      //Log to show data is being returned
      console.log(person)
      return <Row key={(person.StaffID)} person={person.StaffName} />;
    });

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Table bordered responsive>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">#</th>
              <th scope="col">Name</th>
              <th scope="col">In</th>
              <th scope="col">Out</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
        </Table>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Tables;
```

````
import { Button, Collapse } from "react-bootstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "../style/row.css";

class Row extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      signIn: "Sign-in",
      signOut: "Sign-out",
      disabledIn: false,
      disabledOut: false,
      online: "",
      offline: "",
      open: false
    };
  }

  signIn() {
    let today = new Date();
    let time =
      today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
    this.setState({ signIn: time });
    return time;
  }

  signOut() {
    let today = new Date();
    let time =
      today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
    this.setState({ signOut: time });
    return time;
  }

  setStatusOnline() {
    this.setState({
      online: "animated",
      offline: "green",
      disabledOut: false,
      signOut: "Sign-Out"
    });
  }

  setStatusOffline() {
    this.setState({
      offline: "red",
      disabledIn: false,
      signIn: "Sign-In"
    });
  }

  showHistory() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      open: !prevState.open
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <tr>
          <td>{this.props.person.StaffID}</td>
          <td>
            <span
              style={{ backgroundColor: this.state.offline }}
              className={this.state.online}
            ></span>
            {this.props.person.StaffName}
            <Button
              size="sm"
              style={{ marginLeft: "20px" }}
              onClick={() => this.showHistory()}
              variant="info"
            >
              History
            </Button>
            <Collapse in={this.state.open}>
              <div>
                In: {this.state.signIn}
                <br />
                Out:
              </div>
            </Collapse>
          </td>
          <td>
            <Button
              disabled={this.state.disabledIn}
              onClick={() => {
                this.signIn();
                this.setState({ disabledIn: true });
                this.setStatusOnline();
              }}
              variant="success"
            >
              {this.state.signIn}
            </Button>
          </td>
          <td>
            <Button
              disabled={this.state.disabledOut}
              variant="danger"
              onClick={() => {
                this.signOut();
                this.setState({ disabledOut: true });
                this.setStatusOffline();
              }}
            >
              {this.state.signOut}
            </Button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Row;```
````

Comment: In the `rows` map, should this `person={person.StaffName}` just be `person={person}`? It looks like `Row` expects the whole person and not just a property on it.

Comment: @BrianThompson wow... I swear I tried that!! That worked :)

Answer (score 0):

You're passing `person.StaffName` to your Row component as the `person` prop. You should just be passing `person`.

```js
return <Row key={(person.StaffID)} person={person} />;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have passed just staffName in props as person={person.StaffName} which may be a string. try this person={person}